# migration from log4j to log4j2

Tags: maven, logging, log4j, upgrade

My current codebase is a maven project which implements log4j. I have to upgrade from log4j and implement lo4j2 instead. Can anyone direct me to the right resources for doing this which explains the whole process right from step 1 ? The problem is I did not configure log4j in the first place so any help would be great.

I already went through log4j2 offical documentation at logging.apache but couldn't leverage it much.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the docs: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html ? Not enough? Or what is exactly the problem?

Comment: So basically all I have to do is, 
1. add log4j2 dependencies in pom.xml and remove log4j dependencies.
2. convert log4j.xml to log4j2.xml

Is that all ?